# Ayuda lista enlazada sobrescribe string

Tags: c++, lista, archivo, punteros

El problema surge cuando subo los datos de un fichero binario a memoria. No entiendo por qué se sobrescriben los valores del string (Desc.) de cada producto (copiando la descripción del ultimo producto a todos los anteriores) pero los valores numéricos están correctos.
El programa compila, pero cuando muestro la lista por pantalla el resultado es:

```
ID      Desc.                          Cant.         Importe

12      Teclado                         12           1200

04      Teclado                         04           4000

15      Teclado                         15           1500
```

Cuando deberia ser:

```
ID      Desc.                         Cant.          Importe

12      Silla                           12           1200

04      Mesa                            04           4000

15      Teclado                         15           1500
```

Paso el código:

```
template <typename T> struct Node {
     T info;  
     Node<T>* sig; 
};

struct Producto {
 int id;
 string descripcion;
 int len;
 int cantidad;
 long importe;
};

 template <typename T> Node<T>* add(Node<T>*& p, T x)
 {
 Node<T>* nuevo = new Node<T>();
 nuevo->info = x;
 nuevo->sig = NULL;
 if( p==NULL )
 {
    p = nuevo;
 }
 else
 {
    Node<T>* aux = p;
    while( aux->sig!=NULL )
    {
       aux = aux->sig;
    }
    aux->sig = nuevo;
 }
   return nuevo;
 }


Producto productoLeer(FILE* f) {
 Producto producto;
 producto.id = read<int>(f);
 producto.len = read<int>(f);

 for(int i=0; i<producto.len; i++) {
    producto.descripcion[i] = read<char>(f);
 }

 for(int j=producto.len ; j<25 ; j++) {
    producto.descripcion[j] = 32;
 }

 producto.cantidad = read<int>(f);
 producto.importe = read<long>(f);
 return producto;
}


 Node<Producto>* getLista() 
 {
 FILE* inventario = fopen("inventario.DAT", "r+b" );
 long size = fileSize<Producto>(inventario);

 Node<Producto>* listaProductos = NULL;

    for(int i=0; i<size ; i++) 
    {
       Producto producto = productoLeer(inventario);
       add<Producto>(listaProductos, producto);
    }

  showList(listaProductos);

  fclose(inventario);
  return listaProductos;
 }
```

Comment: Donde esta la función read?, la podrías colocar por favor? ( o si me estoy perdiendo algo decirme en que cabecera esta?)

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un caso mínimo y compilable donde se reproduzca el problema?

Comment: @Agustin estás utilizando 2 usuarios diferentes. Por favor utiliza el mismo que hizo la pregunta, que te permite editar tu pregunta y comentar en esta publicación. El otro usuario (el registrado) no tendrá permisos sobre esta pregunta.

Comment: Voto por poner la pregunta en espera hasta que se añada la información necesaria para poder responder a la misma.